# python 2.7's os.stat source code on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, stat

I noticed the following gem in python's source code for ntpath..

```
def islink(path):
    """Test for symbolic link.
    On WindowsNT/95 and OS/2 always returns false
    """
    return False
```

This obviosly isn't the case for vista beyond. So, whenever python encounters a windows symbolic link, it always says that it isn't.  To make things more interesting,

```
x = os.stat(symbolic_link_name)
x.st_mode
16895
import stat
stat.S_ISLNK(x.st_mode)
False
```

Which means stat it's self does not record the ordinals/flags which indicate that the file is a symbolic link.  I would like to fix this or at least point this out to developers, but for the life of me, I can't find the source code for where `os.stat()` is being compiled from.
Where do I go to edit this source code?

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: I added the version into the title. 2.7.10 to be exact though.

Comment: Python 3's `os.ntpath.islink` function is already fixed, so I don't think there's a reason to file a bug report.

Comment: Creating, reading and checking symbolic links on Windows is unlikely to be backported from PY3 to PY2. If you want to add this for a personal build, look at `win32_[w]stat` in Modules/posixmodule.c. You'll want to always use `attributes_from_dir[_w]`, with a `reparse_tag` output parameter added to the function signature. Also add a `reparse_tag` parameter to `attribute_data_to_stat`. When the tag is `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK` set `S_IFLNK` in `st_mode`. I'd also include `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT` (i.e. NTFS junctions), but PY3 doesn't treat these as symbolic links.